# Cordova ble.write i can't send data (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

### I have an Android App build in Apache Cordova, it works with Bluetooth 4.0(BLE) the plugin GitHub repostory indicates this shape for send information to a ble device (in my case a HM10 module):

this function writes data to a characteristic.

ble.write(device_id, service_uuid, characteristic_uuid, data, success, failure);
Description
Function write writes data to a characteristic.

Parameters:
device_id: UUID or MAC address of the peripheral
service_uuid: UUID of the BLE service
characteristic_uuid: UUID of the BLE characteristic
data: binary data, use an ArrayBuffer
success: Success callback function that is invoked when the connection is successful. [optional]
failure: Error callback function, invoked when error occurs. [optional]

---

I have tried to send data for this way but failure function is called immediately

```
    function startBed() {
        var UiidS="FFE0"; //UUID SERVICE: AT+UUID? => 0xFFE0
        var UiidC="FFE1"; //UUID CHARACTERISTICS AT+CHAR? => 0xFFE1

        var data = new Uint8Array(1);
        data[0] = 1;
        setTimeout(ble.write(hMac,UiidS,UiidC,data.buffer,success,failure),2000);
        function success() {
            document.getElementById("btstate1").innerHTML = "Dato enviado!!!";  
            }
        function failure() {
            document.getElementById("btstate1").innerHTML = "Dato NO enviado!!!";  
            var time=2000;
            navigator.vibrate(time);
        }
    }
```

if I take the text box value and send it directly, the HM10 receives an unrecognized characters like Ó.

```
        var UiidS="FFE0";
        var UiidC="FFE1";
        var dato =document.getElementById("btstate6").value;
        setTimeout(ble.write(hMac,UiidS,UiidC,dato,success,failure),2000);
```

In conclution
I don't know why the module not receive the data correctly or in other cases the data isn't send. Maybe is for something of UUID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to solve my problem, I confirmed that the UUID is correct, but I have the doubt about whether I am sending the data well as ArrayBuffer

Answer (score 0):

Using a different plugin (https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle)
I used the following

```
var encodedString = bluetoothle.bytesToEncodedString([145,0,14,0,255]);
bluetoothle.write(this.writeSuccess.bind(this), this.writeError.bind(this), {
        "value": encodedString,
        "service": this.serviceUuid,
        "characteristic": this.serviceCharacteristic,
        "type": "noResponse",
        "address": this.currentConnectedDevice
    });
```

Where

```
// From plugin source:
encodedStringToBytes: function(string) {
    var data = atob(string);
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
},
bytesToEncodedString: function(bytes) {
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes));
},
```

I hope this helps